# How to make a newline in python?

Tags: python

I am new to stack overflow, and new to python. I am on chapter 3 in python. But I am having trouble starting a newline, here's what I have:

```
name = input("Hi. What's your name? ")    
print(name)    
print("Hi,", name)    
name = input("How are you? ")    
print("We are glad you're doing,", name)    
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Please format your code (indent it 4 spaces or hit the {} button while hilighting it).  Also please describe what you _want_ your code to do and what it is really doing, including all relevant errors.

Comment: didnt understand your problem!!

Comment: Try to use the '\n' escape character inside your print function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\n`, it is a line break, and you need a backslash to escape it

So, for example

```
print(name+'\n')
```

will print it with a linebreak.

Since it is unclear of what you are trying to do, the above will have two linebreaks as DietrichEpp mentioned, as `print()` will write a `'\n'` character at the end.

Comment: That will print with two linebreaks, since `print()` adds a linebreak.

Comment: Thank you all for the help :)